# Quantum Field Regularization: Choice between ExpIntegralE and Gamma for Casimir Effect

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, summation, algebraic-manipulation

For the [Casimir effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect#Regularization) with exponential regularization, we compute the vacuum energy between the plates (somewhat simplified) with:
$$\omega = c\ \sqrt{q^2+k_z^2}$$
$$ E = \sum_{k_z=n\pi/a} 2 \int \frac{qdq}{2\pi} \ \frac{{\small \hbar}}{\small 2}  \ \omega\ e^{-\omega/C} $$
In Mathematica, ignoring some constant factors, first doing the integral

```
    w = c Sqrt[kz^2+q^2]
    Int = Integrate[q/2/Pi w Exp[-w/C], {q,0,Infinity}, Assumptions->{C>0,c>0,kz>0}]
```

leads to `c*kz^3*ExpIntegralE[-2, (c*kz)/C]/(2*Pi)`. Unfortunately, this gives failure to compute the subsequent sum  `Ecas = Sum[ Int /.kz->Pi/a n, {n,1,Infinity}]`.

The integral could have been expressed using an incomplete $\Gamma$ function  `altInt = C^3/(2Pi c^2) Gamma[3, kz c/C]` (check `FullSimplify[altInt==Int]` gives True!) In that case Mathematica *does* find the sum: `Ecas = Sum[ altInt/.kz->Pi/a n, {n,1,Infinity}]` and with cutoff parameter $C \rightarrow \infty$, `Series[Ecas, {C,Infinity,0}]` then correctly shows the $1/a^3$ term leading to the Casimir effect.

So it is unfortunate that Mathematica did not choose to express the integral as a gamma function... Strangely, if we leave out the assumptions for the integral, we do get a conditional expression, but it *does* in that case choose the gamma function. Also, if we give `Assumptions->{C>0,c>0}` but leave out the `kz>0`, then we even get the gamma function without the conditional expression! So questions are:

1. Why does Mathematica solve this problem with less assumptions and fails with *more help* by an extra assumption?
2. Why does the choice of how to express the integral depend on the details of the given assumptions along the way? In the end both expressions are exactly the same.
3. Why does the sum fail for the expression with `ExpIntegralE` even though it is exactly equal to the expression with `Gamma` for which the sum *can* be evaluated?

PS: (edited) thanks to the comments and answers we have now established that with $\omega = \sqrt{q^2+k_z^2}$, so using $c=1$, we have:

PS: (edited) thanks to the comments and answers we have now established that with $\omega = \sqrt{q^2+k_z^2}$, so using $c=1$, we have:
$$ \int \frac{q\ dq}{2\pi} \ \omega\ e^{-\omega/C} 
   =     \frac{C^3}{2\pi}\ \Gamma(3, \frac{k_z}C) = $$
$$ =   \frac{k_z^3}{2\pi} E_{-2}(\frac{k_z}{C}) \ =  \left(C^3+C^2 k_z + C k_z^2/2\right) \ e^{-k_z/C} $$

Comment: Can you provide fully-functional code?  For example, `Int` as written evaluates to the wrong thing because I don't have a definition of w, and when I tried to put it in I got that Int, is C^2 Γ[3, kz/C]/2π, since I let c=1.  So it's tricky reproduce your exact issue.  

Orthogonally, typically when studying the Casimir effect the energy is divergent in a regulator-dependent way but the force is finite.  So you might be better off differentiating before summing.

Comment: Here we see the shadow effect. `C` is a system symbol. So it could be better to use `c1` instead of `C`. The transition `Series[Ecas, {C,Infinity,0}]` you are making is incorrect. It's just a miracle that you got some results there. In the future, when you evaluate such expressions, try to minimize the number of constants used.

Comment: @evanb Sorry for the omission, I now added it (I got lot's of "not submitted, wrong code formatting" when I tried to submit the question and then it got lost... Apologies from a newbe!)

Comment: @Alex I see no difference when I rename `C` to `Coff`, I still get the `ExpIntegralE`. (And actually I didn't know `C` was a system variable, I wouldn't use `E` or `N`, but `C` looked innocent and it is closest to what we physicists use for "cutoff". I do see the difference when I replace "c" by 1, but that just re-iterates the question: why is the function chosen by `Integrate` so dependent on these little details?

Comment: I always use Λ for cutoff :)

Comment: @evanb Excellent choice, sir, but to get short ASCII code snippets for the posted question, I opted foc `C` instead of `Lambda`. Anyhow, the 'using non-ASCII in programming languages' question might be a bit off-topic in this thread...

Comment: @JosBergervoet Please see tutorial `C[i]
is the default form for the i\[Null]\[Null]^th parameter or constant generated in representing the results of various symbolic computations`.

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

w = c  Sqrt[kz^2 + q^2];
```

Use [`FunctionExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html)

```
Int = Assuming[{Coff > 0, c > 0, kz > 0},
  Integrate[q/2/Pi  w  Exp[-w/Coff], {q, 0, Infinity}] // 
   FunctionExpand // Simplify]

(* (Coff E^(-((c kz)/Coff)) (2 Coff^2 + 2 c Coff kz + c^2 kz^2))/(2 c^2 π) *)
```

This is equivalent to your alternate representation.

```
Int == Coff^3/(2 Pi  c^2)  Gamma[3, kz  c/Coff] // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

The summation is

```
Ecas = Sum[Int /. kz -> Pi/a  n, {n, 1, Infinity}] //
  FullSimplify

(* (2 a^2 Coff^3 - 
   Coff E^((c π)/(
    a Coff)) (4 a^2 Coff^2 + 2 a c Coff π - c^2 π^2) + 
   Coff E^((2 c π)/(
    a Coff)) (2 a^2 Coff^2 + 2 a c Coff π + c^2 π^2))/(2 a^2 c^2 (-1 +
      E^((c π)/(a Coff)))^3 π) *)
```

Comment: Indeed `FunctionExpand` does the job, as a bonus it even shows us that the expression does not need any special functions at all! I think we here have found  the simplest  "demonstration calculation" of the  Casimir effect.